# Rollback SSIS Data Flow Tasks if one fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my SSIS package I have several data flow tasks.

Is there a way in SSIS which says if the F0101Z2 task completes but the F03012Z1 fails rollback what was passed in the F0101Z2 step?

[image: My SSIS package]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set `TransactionOption=Required` on Package Level, and configure all Tasks to `TransactionOption=Supported`**(by default Supported)**. They will all join the transaction, and if any fail, the transaction will be rolled back.
Note: First Make Sure that MSDTC(MS Distributed Transaction Co-coordinator) is enabled in the `Control Panel--->Admin tool-->Services.`

Comment: If you find that the process ends up getting hung up after you make this switch, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508594/ssis-data-flow-task-hangs-on-excecution-of-pre-excecute-phase 
You may just need to change a option or two on some of your components and connections

Answer (score 0):

Just study these **Links** and you will be able to solve your Problem.

**[how to use transactions in sql server integration services ssis/](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)**

**[SSIS transaction management MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012358/ssis-transaction-management-mssql)**

**[How to transaction rollback in ssis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626755/how-to-transaction-rollback-in-ssis)**

Comment: thanks for the links, very useful. my next problem is I'm sending data from ms sql to oracle using global temp tables so i need to set the connection managers to retain same connection. this seems to cause the sequence container to fail if i do this and if i don't retain the same connection further steps fail. looks as if sequence container isn't for me on this occasion.